# Error when creating a stored procedure in postgreSQL-10

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, errors, postgresql-10

I couldn't get my first stored procedure to work, so I copied this example from the manual:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data(a integer, b integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (a);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (b);
$$;

CALL insert_data(1, 2);
```

and I get the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
> LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data(a integer, b integer)
>                ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 8
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running the database on localhost, running as admin user. I installed it myself. Installation process completed without errors, and I am able to create tables, functions, triggers, etc.

Comment: ... **can't** use them in Postgres 10 is what @a_horse meant to say.

Comment: That's crazy! Any semi-decent SQL should have stored procedures...Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GrannyAching: just create a function - you can do essentially everything with them as well. Or just upgrade to Postgres 11

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need to insert statement to insert to rows: `insert into tbl values (a), (b);` would do just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I could upgrade to 11 on my local copy. But we have 10 running in production, and I want the same testing environment. About your second (unrelated) comment, I copied and pasted the sample code from the manual.

Comment: I'm surprised that this question is labelled off-topic. Version 10 is still widely used, so I'm sure someone else switching to PostgreSQL could end up using 10 and expect stored procedures to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, PostgreSQL-10 does **not** have stored procedures. Same is true about earlier versions.

Workaround alternatives:

- Upgrade to version 11 or later
- Use a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createfunction.html)

Thanks, @Erwin Brandstetter and @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Even in PostgreSQL 12, PROCEDURE is not supported.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli v12 has them, at least according to the output of `pg_dump --schema-only`.